# Append / add, text and function to a div's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I'm currently working on a [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) based application. I'm using the `'pascalprecht.translate'` library to create a multi-language application. For more information on that please see this  [link](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). While creating my application i've created a dynamic switch of page titles. this switch reads the route name from the `$routeProvider` and adds a corresponding title to the `<header>`. See the example below:

```
// Pages configuration
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {

    document.title = $route.current.title;
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;

    var leftSvg = document.getElementById('leftsvg');
    var rightSvg = document.getElementById('rightsvg');


    // start responsive elements
        $("footer").removeClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#header").removeClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#leftheaderblock").removeAttr('class');
        $("#rightheaderblock").removeAttr('class');
        $(".activefooter").removeAttr('class');
        $("#homepageback").removeClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#rightsvg").addClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#leftsvg").addClass("hidden-xl-down");

        $("body").removeAttr('class');
        $("body").addClass(title);

    if (title === 'login') {
        $("footer").addClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#header").addClass("hidden-xl-down")
    }

    else if (title === 'productpage') {
        $("#homepageback").addClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#homesvg").addClass("activefooter");
        $("#leftheaderblock").addClass("col-55");
        $("#rightheaderblock").addClass("col-45");
        $('#leftheadertext').text('Alle producten');
        $('#rightheadertext').text('Bestelling');
        $("#rightsvg").removeClass("hidden-xl-down");
        $("#leftsvg").removeClass("hidden-xl-down")

    }
});
```

}]);

**The html**
The `<html>` is some simple div's in an index.html file. Below you'll see the example of the `rightheaderblock`.

```
<div id="rightheaderblock">
    <div class="bc-f3f3f3 justify-content-center toptext d-flex align-items-center headerblock">
        <span id="rightheadertext"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The question**

Using `'pascalprecht.translate'` gives access to the possibility of creating a multiple language application with your own language library's in `JSON` format. See the example below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','pascalprecht.translate','ngSanitize']);
var mypagetitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login_view.html',
            title: 'login'
        })

        .when('/productpage', {
            templateUrl: 'views/productpage_view.html',
            title: 'productpage'
        })

        .when('/payorder', {
            templateUrl: 'views/payorder_view.html',
            title: 'payorder'
        });
    $translateProvider
        .translations('en', {
            'Opslaan': 'Save',
            'Alle producten': 'All products',
            'Bestelling': 'Order',
        })
        .translations('nl', {
            'Opslaan': 'Opslaan',
            'Alle producten': 'Alle producten',
            'Bestelling': 'Bestelling',
        });
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl'); // standaard taal bij openen
    // configures staticFilesLoader
    // configures staticFilesLoader
});

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.text = "hi";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id="rightheaderblock">
        <div class="bc-f3f3f3 justify-content-center toptext d-flex align-items-center headerblock">
          <span id="rightheadertext">
            {{text}}
          </span>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyTests">
    <p> {{ "Bestelling" | translate }} 
  </div>
```

Above you're able to look at a simple example of how the `'tranlate'` function works. by adding `| translate` to a string and defining that string to a `.translations()` section i'm able to create the translations.

Looking back at the `// Pages configuration` above you're able to see that i'm using `if/else` statements to check for the page title and add `.text()` and `classes` to a div by current page title.

The issue i'm having is passing the `| translate` section of e.g. `{{"bestelling" | translate}}` from the `if/else` statement to the view. So passing the following line:

```
$('#rightheadertext').text('Bestelling');
```

To the page isn't a problem. But adding

```
$('#rightheadertext').text('{{ Bestelling | translate }}');
```

gives me the full string in the view:

```
{{ Bestelling | translate }}
```

i've tried multiple different functions like `.val()` and `append()`. But neither seems to work. The result i would like is to add the following structure to the view:

```
{{ "string" | translate // call }}
```

If you have any questions or remarks on my question please let them know in the comments below.

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem here, I believe, is you are trying to get jQuery to update the text but you want to use Angular's expression replacement. Those two things can't be used together like that. You want to avoid using jQuery like that and just rely on Angular to do the work.

Comment: @benjaminhull I'm aware that using `JQuery` in combination with Angular isn't the correct way. But for now these are my examples and what i've tried. I'm still also looking and possible `Angularjs` ways to achieve the result i would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
<p> {{ $root.text1 | translate }}</p>
```

Then in your code, in the if/else...

```
if (...) {
    $rootScope.text1 = 'Bestelling';
} else {
    $rootScope.text1 = 'Opslaan';
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm (: Thanks!

Comment: Phew - I didn't actually test it, so wasn't 100% certain. Glad it worked. It's hard to shift from the jQuery to Angular mindset.